# ASP.NET Resource handler mechanism in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, localization, cultureinfo, currentuiculture

Simple. I want to localize my application.
I've googled for days, and tried a million different approaches to reach my resources.
The only way I've been succesful is by using the standard asp.net folders "App_LocalResource", making the resource files public and giving them a `Custom Tool Name`. In the view I can then import the `Custom Tool Name` with `@using`.

My issue is that the language/resource items arent changing when I change the culture.

Here is how I change it in global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {
            CultureInfo ci = (CultureInfo)this.Session["Culture"];
            if (ci == null)
            {
                string langName = "en";
                string autoLang = "";
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages.Length != 0)
                {
                    autoLang = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages[0].Substring(0, 2);
                }
                if (autoLang == "da")
                    langName = autoLang;
                ci = new CultureInfo(langName);
                this.Session["Culture"] = ci;
            }

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
        }
    }
```

So the culture is either `da` or `en`. But I noticed that the names of the resource files has to have a specific syntax. There has to be a default (in this case english) with no country/culture code and other that default has be named like reFile.da-DK.resx. It has to have both language and culture code.

I'm affraid the resource handler can recognize my file, because culture is set to "da" and not "da-DK". If I name my `da` resouce file to resFile.da.resx I cant import the `Custom Tool Name` which is my resouce files.

What do I do to solve this?

Comment: Why is the full culture name not available here in each case?

Comment: @AdamTuliper-MSFT CurrentUICulture only accepts two letter strings.

Comment: CurrentUICulture accepts a CultureInfo which is a full name (not two char) such as new CultureInfo("en-US"), also I'd set this in BeginRequest, it occurs earlier in the page lifecycle and is typically the place this code finds itself.

Comment: @AdamTuliper-MSFT Yes. I used full name CultureInfo like you said, and split the string up in two when only the first bit was needed.

Comment: ok, added below as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the full culture info string, ex:

```
var info = new CultureInfo("en-US")
```

Also for best practice move the code out into the Application_BeginRequest method, that's the standard location you'll see this type of code.